# JSON mal formatado

Tags: php, json

Olá, amigos.

Estou gerando um arquivo .json com PHP, mas o mesmo quando é criado está mal formatado, não é possível ler seus dados. Vejam:

```
{
"0": "6",
"idt1": "6",
"1": "2018-10-19",
"datahora": "2018-10-19",
"2": "1",
"resultado": "1",
"3": "1",
"indicbet": "1",
"4": "Inglaterra - Premier League 2",
"LIGA": "Inglaterra - Premier League 2",
"5": "",
"rh": "",
"6": "",
"ra": "",
"7": " Fulham SubWest Brom Sub",
"TIMEHA": " Fulham SubWest Brom Sub",
"8": "71",
"TARGLG": "71",
"9": "0",﻿
"PLACH": "0",
"10": "2",
"PLACA": "2",
"11": "GREEN",
"RESULT": "GREEN"
}{
"0": "6",
"idt1": "6",
"1": "2018-10-19",
"datahora": "2018-10-19",
"2": "1",
"resultado": "1",﻿
"3": "1",
"indicbet": "1",
"4": "Inglaterra - Premier League 2",
"LIGA": "Inglaterra - Premier League 2",
"5": "",
"rh": "",
"6": "",
"ra": "",
"7": " Fulham SubWest Brom Sub",
"TIMEHA": " Fulham SubWest Brom Sub",
"8": "71",
"TARGLG": "71",
"9": "0",
"PLACH": "0",
"10": "2",
"PLACA": "2",
"11": "GREEN",
"RESULT": "GREEN"
}
```

Como podem ver, faltam os colchetes no início e no fim e as vírgulas entre os "arrays".

Aqui o código que gera o json:

```
w﻿hile($rowJ = mysqli_fetch_array($resultJ)){ 
if(count($_items) > 1){
//criar JSON/tabela do USUARIO
                   // Escreve o resultado JSON em arquivo:
                   $idu = $_SESSION['idu_log_pn'];
                   $idu = 1;
                   $pasta = $idu;
                   $diretorio = "users﻿/".$pasta;

                   if(!file_exists($diretorio))
                   {
                    mkdir("$diretorio", 0777);
                   }﻿﻿



// Tranforma o array $dados em JSON
$dados_json = json_encode($rowJ, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

// Cria o arquivo cadastro.json
// O parâmetro "a" indica que o arquivo será aberto para escrita
$fp = fopen("users/".$idu."/file".$idu.".json", "a");

// Escreve o conteúdo JSON no arquivo
$escreve = fwrite($fp, $dados_json);

// Fecha o arquivo
fclose($fp);
                  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ao invés de **abrir**, **escrever** e **fechar** o arquivo a cada iteração no seu laço de repetição, por que não mantê-lo aberto durante o processo?

Aliás, o problema está que você está formatando para JSON um *array* associativo e escrevendo diretamente no arquivo no modo APPEND. Ou seja, pro JSON esse conteúdo nunca foi uma lista, então não tem motivos para ele adicionar os colchetes, muito menos as vírgulas entre os registros. Se você quer formatar para JSON uma lista, passe uma lista.

```
$data = [];

while ($rowJ = mysqli_fetch_array($resultJ)) {
  if(count($_items) > 1){
    // ...
    $data[] = $rowJ;
  }
}

$dados_json = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

$fp = fopen("users/{$idu}/file{$idu}.json", "w");

$escreve = fwrite($fp, $dados_json);

fclose($fp);
```

Assim o que você estará formatando para JSON é um *array* de objetos, gerando o resultado esperado.

Você pode também usar [`file_put_content`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-put-contents.php) para salvar o conteúdo no arquivo ao invés de `fopen`, `fwrite` e `fclose`:

```
file_put_contents("users/{$idu}/file{$idu}.json", $dados_json);
```

Comment: Anderson, funcionou certinho... Obrigado, cara!